# Function windows.print print two pages

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a div in my HTML which I want to print

```
<div class="operationVaccin">
Content
</div>
```

I'm using the function windows.print() in my TypeScript file.

```
printVaccin(){
    setTimeout(() => { window.print(); }, 1000);
  }
```

My problem is I get the same page printed two times.

My CSS file:

```
@media print {
    .operationVaccin {
        overflow: visible !important;
        float:none !important;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        display:block !important;
        height: 100vw !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without having seen your code, I believe you might not be hiding the other content?

Consider adding CSS handling this:

```
@media print {
    .operationVaccin {
        //... as in your question
    }

    .notToShow {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is the same content is printed two times.

Comment: Please provide more of the HTML you're rendering... I'm guessing your page doesn't solely consist of a `div`. Is the `<div class="operationVaccin">Content</div>` the root element of your page?